# Aurora replicas

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

Aurora enables you to create a primary writer and a secondary reader. I understand that replicas can be made for the reader to give high availability.

> What I don't understand is what's the use when one replicates the writer? I means it's only job is to perform writes. How does a replica for it help?

Comment: You don't replicate writer per se but If your writer goes down, one of the reader will be promoted as writer.

Comment: Thanks man. Maybe the replica of the writer be made as the new writer in case of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about writes only, Aurora supports [multi-master](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-multi-master.html) architectures. In them all db instances are read-write, and there is no such thing as read replicas, as all the instances are equal.

The primary use of it is for situations with zero-tolerance for downtime in writes. When you use regular Aurora clusters (1 write + read replicas), when writer goes down, there is short period of downtime during which no writes are going to happen. This downtime is due to period required to promote one of the read replicas to be the new writer.

In some cases, such downtime in writes is unacceptable. This is where multi-master clusters can be useful.

Multi-master clusters are very special. They have bunch of their own limitations, so their use-cases are rather limited.

The multi-master architecture is supported only for the My-SQL compatible version.